# Unable to access object methods after casting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to access some of my object of a model methods but keep getting an error that there is no such function.

This is the model class I wrote :

```
class Expense {
  private name: string;
  private title: string;
  private amount: number;
  private description: string;
  private date: Date;
  private status: string;
  public formatetdDate: string;
  private _id : string;
  constructor(name: string, title: string, amount: number, description: string, date: Date, status: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.title = title;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.description = description;
    this.date = new Date(0);
    this.status = status;
    this.formatetdDate = this.dateFormat();
  }

  public getDate(): Date {
    return this.date;
  }
  public dateFormat(): string {

    let dd = this.date.getDate();
    let mm = this.date.getMonth() + 1;
    const yyyy = this.date.getFullYear();

    if (dd < 10) {
      dd = +`0${dd}`;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
      mm = +`0${mm}`;
    }
    console.log(dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy);
    return dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
  }
}
export default Expense;
```

Now I am retrieving the data from the server using http calls and casting it to this model :

```
   this.expenseService.getExpensesList().subscribe((expenses) => {
      if (expenses.success) {
        this.expensesList = expenses.data as Expense[];
        this.total = +expenses.total;
        this.pages = +expenses.pages;
        this.limit = +expenses.limit;
      } else {
        alert(expenses.message);
      }
    });
```

if ill try to do the folllowing action :

```
this.expensesList[0].getData()
```

or

```
this.expensesList[0].dateFormat()
```

its always throwing an error that those are no functions.
but if i will try to print the date (this.expensesList[0].date)
it will throw an errordue to access violation (private)

what am i doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the result of this: console.log(this.expensesList) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as Expense[]` is merely a *type hint*, telling Typescript that `expenses.data` is in fact an array of `Expense` object, despite what else Typescript might have inferred. But, well, they are *not* `Expense` objects, they're mere plain objects (or so I assume). You will need to actually loop through the data and create `new Expense` objects from them for them to become `Expense` objects, which will have a `getDate` method.

> but if i will try to print the date (`this.expensesList[0].date`) it will throw an errordue to access violation (private)

Yes, because you have convinced the static type checker that you're trying to access the property of an `Expense` object (whether that is actually true or not).

That's why you should use `as` sparingly and only when you really know what you're doing; it can prevent the type checker from doing its job and those problems will only surface at runtime without being caught at compile time.

Comment: thanks a lot.
so when i am retreving a reults from db,in my case Mongo,i will have to do it manually? i mean looping and using nre Expense? it dose not seems effeciant.currently its just 20 items but when it will go to production it will be wat more then that.is there any "right" way to do that?

Comment: Mongo does not return objects which have a `getDate` method. `as Expense[]` doesn't do actual type casting. So, yes, if you want to have objects which have a `getDate` method, you'll need to add it to each object at some point. Since Javascript is very flexible with its prototype-based language, perhaps you can just futz around with each objects prototype to attach those methods after the fact, instead of going through a constructor. But then again, you typically want to go through a constructor to be able to make certain guarantees about type safety.